# How do I plot the time series data in R?

Tags: r, plot

If I have the following data set

How can I use the data above to draw a graph like the one below? Where the x-axis is for each year and the y-axis draws 10 data for each year and gives a qu shi of their data

[image]

Comment: You can obtain the first plot by `df_long <- reshape2::melt(data = venice, id.vars = 'year');
plot(value ~ year, data = df_long, bty = 'n', type = 'p', pch = 19)` That said, I'm not entirely sure what the second plot represents? Can you provide some further detail?

Comment: just FYI... your second sample plot seems to be based on data that runs from approx 1876 - 1980... that's not the same as `VGAM::venice`. The code I provide that plots the yearly mean of the 10 data points uses `VGAM::venice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(VGAM)
data(venice)

df_long <- reshape2::melt(data = venice, id.vars = 'year')
plot(value ~ year, data = df_long, bty = 'n', type = 'p', pch = 19)
```

[image: scatter plot 1]

```r
plot(value ~ year, data = df_long, bty = 'n', type = 'p', pch = '*') 
lines(venice[ , 1 ], venice[ , -1 ] |> rowMeans(), lwd = 2, col = 'blue')
```

[image: scatter plot with rowMeans]

Comment: Literally the only difference between the two scatterplots is the `pch` value. Perhaps the smaller "*" dots make the relationship easier to spot?